# How to check the very next checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

The issue I face is that I have identical "button-checkboxes", but once one of of them is clicked, I only want the closest checkbox check and uncheck.

```
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-private">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o private"></i>
     <button>
     <input name="private" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
</span>
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-private">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o private"></i>
     <button>
     <input name="private" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
</span>
```

The JavaScript code I currently use is:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-private", function() {

    $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);

})
```

For some odd reason, `$(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');` correctly toggles the classes, but it seems that `$(this).find('input:checkbox')` does not get correctly selected, because if I manually assign an ID and `$('#ID').prop("checked", true);` it gets correctly checked.

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue and how I can uncheck the box on click as well, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Define closest, is it similar to next or prev?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-private", function() {
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
    $(this).next().prop("checked", true); // here
})
```

Otherwise you are looking for checkbox inside button.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);` is looking for the `input` inside the `button`.

Try looking at the next element after the button:

`$(this).next().find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);`

here is a working codepen:
http://codepen.io/ZevanRosser/pen/wgjOQE